# Database .sdf File Not Found

Tags: c#, windows, sql-server-ce

I am developing an application on Win 6 sdk with SQL Server CE for smart devices.

Problem is it throws an error while opening the SQL Server CE connection
it says

> The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [ Path = Data Source=.\Database\SFAHabib.sdf ]

My connection string:

[image: I ve tried full path too..]

[image: Here is my function where iam opening the connection]

Comment: Do not post code as pictures, we want the text to be on Google.

Comment: So where is your  `.\\`  folder? Find out.

Comment: You can use App_data folder as a database directory

Comment: thanks Henk, I ll be careful next time..

I got the solution.. I ve posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.. actually I was giving the file location of my system ..
but emulator uses the location where app is installed.. in my case it was under Program files in the emulator.. so when i gave location like that.. then it worked

public mDataBase()
        {
            try
            {

```
            string StartupPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
            string datalogicFilePath = Path.Combine(StartupPath, "Database\\SFAHabib.sdf");
            mConnStr = string.Format("DataSource={0}", datalogicFilePath);
            msqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection(mConnStr); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```